# Using a laptop with multiple static-ip routers

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, static-ip, mac-address

I use my Windows XP laptop with Wi-Fi at school, home, work and by my parents. Each of these has a different setup (one DHCP and the other three use different static IPs). Is there a way  to attach a pre-configured setup to a router MAC or to a SSID?  That way when I get connected to an access-point, it will automatically use the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This module allow you to configure, test, save, and restore 802.11 wireless network settings for your card or cards.  Once the configuration has been tested, verified, and saved, it can be used in NetSwitcher as a part of the normal profile for a location where you work.  As you build a database of locations where you use wireless services, you will finally be able to immediately get to work rather then "fiddling" with 802.11 wireless settings.

The SiteMonitor™ site survey let you see quickly what wireless networks are in range and what their characteristics are.  The real-time display can also be used to find the best orientation for your laptop and/or antenna when operating in fringe reception locations.

Source: http://www.netswitcher.com/WirelessProfileManager.htm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops have a tool included from the vendor.  Lenovo for example has a connection manager that can assist.  What make is the laptop?

Comment: It is from MSI.